Error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5
I am trying to write a basic client for Postgres integration in C using libpq, I compiled the libraries following the Client-only installation on this page and so far so good, I compile my program with the following:
cc -o connect connect.c -I/usr/local/pgsql/include -L/usr/local/pgsql/lib -lpq

and by running the program this is the output:
./connect: error while loading shared libraries: libpq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I correctly compiled all the libraries and libpq.so.5 is on the system:
plocate libpq.so.5 return /usr/local/pgsql/lib/libpq.so.5
Could anyone help me with this? What am I missing?
Thanks in advance

I am thinking if it can be due to order of arguments in compilation command, but then it would have thrown the error during compilation and not during runtime. Maybe just try running ldd connect and see what it outputs.

what does $LD_LIBRARY_PATH show ? if /usr/local/pgsql/lib isn't on it ....

What operating system are you running it on? For Linux, you need to configure the dynamic linker runtime bindings by listing the custom library directories in /etc/ld.so.conf or /etc/ld.so.conf.d/*.conf and then run sudo ldconfig which will update the /etc/ld.so.cache file. (See the man page for ldconfig.)

That your libpgsql is installed in /usr/local suggests that you may have built it from source, yourself.  This should be a last resort under most circumstances.  Chances are good that both development and runtime libpgsql components are available pre-packaged for your OS, and such packages are usually a better choice: someone else will have figured out all of the build and installation nuances that otherwise, you would have to deal with yourself.  Such as configuring the dynamic linker.

I am running Arch linux, but I'm trying to build it for source since this cose will be deployed on others Linux distros (Debian, Centos and others) and keeping things as small as possible is a requirement.
I'm trying to configure /etc/ld.so.conf by adding include /usr/local/pgsql/lib/ and running sudo ldconfig but the output doesn't change
